# Error sharing Angular URL on Facebook share button, href formatting

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I'm trying to share the following URL via a facebook share button:

```
https://zoobl.com/build/#/class/17
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
href is not properly formatted
```

I've figured out that it doesn't like the # symbol in the URL but I can't figure out how to get around it.

Comment: Try encoding and see what happens '%23' for #

Comment: So that got me past the 'href is not properly formatted' error, but it seems like the share box is chopping off anything after the # now

Comment: ok .. probably you need to encode uniformly. the entire url